# Terraform fails to create a 64-bit Azure App Service (Web app)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform version 0.15.5 (and also 0.15.4) to provision an Azure Web App resource. The following configuration works fine:

```json
 site_config {
    http2_enabled             = true
    always_on                 = false
    use_32_bit_worker_process = true
  }
```

But when I use `use_32_bit_worker_process = false` to get the script provision a 64-bit web app, it fails and I get the following error message:

```
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6392592Z [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating App Service "gfdemogatewayapp" (Resource Group "MASKED"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>[0m
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6411094Z [31m│[0m [0m
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6426506Z [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with azurerm_app_service.gfgatewayapp,
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6427703Z [31m│[0m [0m  on main.tf line 274, in resource "azurerm_app_service" "gfgatewayapp":
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6428766Z [31m│[0m [0m 274: resource "azurerm_app_service" "gfgatewayapp" [4m{[0m[0m
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6429584Z [31m│[0m [0m
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6430461Z [31m╵[0m[0m
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6534148Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.15.4/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
2021-06-03T18:06:55.6548186Z ##[section]Finishing: Terraform approve and apply
```

Is there something that I am missing or terraform has an issue in provisioning the 64-bit web app resource on Azure?

**UPDATE: The full source code**
The tier is Standard and the SKU size is "F1".

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "gfwebappserviceplan" {
  name                = var.gatewayserviceplanname
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.gf.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.gf.name}"

  sku {
    tier = var.gatewayserviceplanskutier
    size = var.gatewayserviceplanskusize
  }
}
resource "azurerm_app_service" "gfgatewayapp" {
  name                = var.gatewayappname
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.gf.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.gf.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.gfwebappserviceplan.id
  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "${azurerm_application_insights.gfapplicationinsights.instrumentation_key}"
  }

  site_config {
    http2_enabled             = true
    always_on                 = false
    use_32_bit_worker_process = false
  }
}

output "gfgatewayhostname" {
  value = "${azurerm_app_service.gfgatewayapp.default_site_hostname}"
  description = "Gateway default host name"
}

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "webapp-corestack" {
  # This will make it .NET CORE for Stack property, and add the dotnet core logging extension
  name                = "AspNetCoreStack"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.gf.name}"
  template_body       = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "siteName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Azure App Service Name"
            }
        },
        "extensionName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Site Extension Name."
            }
        },
        "extensionVersion": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Extension Version"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [],
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "dotnetcore"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'), '/', parameters('extensionName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "version": "[parameters('extensionVersion')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
  DEPLOY
  parameters = {
    "siteName"         = azurerm_app_service.gfgatewayapp.name
    "extensionName"    = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension"
    "extensionVersion" = "3.1.7"
  }
  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  depends_on      = [azurerm_app_service.gfgatewayapp]
}
```

Comment: Could you share your resource creation and dependencies? Also maybe it has something to do with your underlying `app service`

Comment: @SamVruggink I updated the question by adding the source code in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using a `F1` tier `app service plan`. `Free` or `Shared` tiers do not have a 64 bit option.

[Terraform AzureRM Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#use_32_bit_worker_process)

Comment: @Arash `D1` is still a shared instance. Try setting it to `B1` or `S1`.

Answer (score 11):

Since this is the first google result you get when searching for

> "AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0"

and that was my error, I will try to help other people that might stumble over this problem.
What I did was migrating a function from azure provider version 2.x to 3.x. Since terraform actually changed the resource type from azurerm_function_app to azurerm_windows_function_app they also changed some properties.
What happened for me was that they added the properties `application_insights_key` and `application_insights_connection_string` to the `site_config`. Before you had to manually (in the `app_settings`) add a key called `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`.
I used the new setting but forgot to get rid of the manually added key and my function creation was failing with the above (not very verbose if you ask me) error.

Took me a while to figure that out, so that's why I'm sharing this here.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes, thanks for pointing in the right direction!
here were APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY, FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME, FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION, FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION app settings

Comment: Got this because I was trying to deploy an app service on a subnet that was already used by another plan.

Answer (score 7):

If setting `use_32_bit_worker_process` or `use_32_bit_worker` to `true` does not help, then try to run terraform with logging. Logging can be enabled by setting the `TF_LOG` environment variable, e.g.:

```
$ TF_LOG=debug terraform apply
```

This will produce a lot of logging, including the HTTP responses from Azure. One of the last logged responses should include more details about the cause. In my case it was because `always_on` is not supported on the free plan, but is enabled by default:

```
HTTP/2.0 409 Conflict
<snip>
{"Code":"Conflict","Message":"There was a conflict. AlwaysOn cannot be set for this site as the plan does not allow it. [...]}
```

Comment: Best answer so far. It has happened to me also. With this answer, I found the root cause: "There was a conflict. AlwaysOn cannot be set for this site as the plan does not allow it. For more information on pricing and features, please see: https://aka.ms/appservicepricingdetails".

Comment: Very good answer on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Slots Require a Standard or Premium Service Plan

I ran into this and, similarly to others, found this SO answer.  Check your Service Plan and make sure it's not a Basic or Free tier, you cannot create Slots on those plans